# Yarn is running only 361 of 1341 test cases

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, yarnpkg

Actually, I'm working on a project with more than 1300 test cases. I've already cloned the whole project again but it seems to be a problem with my npm. When I do `yarn test` only 361 of 1341 tests run, I have no idea of what I can do to fix it, does anybody know what is going on?

I'm using the following command:

`TZ=utc NODE_ENV=test NODE_PATH=./ mocha --colors --require Tests/support.js --reporter spec Domain/**/*.test.js Infra/**/*.test.js`

There is no `.only` or things like that.

I'm using node version 8.9.4 with npm version 5.6.0 installed with nvm.

This is the output from my computer:
[image]

And this is the output from our codeship:
[image]

#### Update

Even when I use `.only` on any test case, it ignores and does the same output. I've uninstalled yarn and still not working.

Comment: Is this the same command verbatim from codeship?

Comment: Have you tried the recursive flag?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, after reinstalling node and nvm everything is working fine now, the only problem is that I don't know what exactly was the problem.

Comment: @Jack yes, the commands are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling node and nvm, everything is working fine now. I don't know exactly how to solve the problem.